# Use method and state of functional component with React Navigation setOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation v5's `setOptions` API to customize my header buttons and access functions inside of a functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default ({ navigation }) => {

    const [text, setText] = useState('initialValue');

    console.log('render - text is now: ' + text);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit}>
                    <View style={{marginRight: 18, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'white', borderRadius: 17.5, width: 35, height: 35}}>
                        {/* FontAwesome icon omitted for brevity */}
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        });
    }, [navigation]);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('submit - text is now: ' + text);
    };

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
            <TextInput
                style={{width: '100%'}}
                multiline
                autoGrow
                value={text}
                onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

When I use this component and change the text, I can see the correct "render - text is now: ..." output on the console.

However, when I click the header button and the `handleSubmit` method is called, I see "submit - text is now: initialValue", regardless of my changes.

I fail to see what I might be doing wrong here, please advise.

Versions:
* react: 16.11.0
* react-native: 0.62.2
* @react-navigation/native: 5.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the text as a dependency for the useLayoutEffect for it to work

```
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit}>
                    <View style={{marginRight: 18, borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'white', borderRadius: 17.5, width: 35, height: 35}}>
                        {/* FontAwesome icon omitted for brevity */}
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        });
    }, [navigation,text]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working! Can you explain /why/ I need it? My understanding is that this effectively re-sets the navigation options upon every `text` change, but the actual options don't change - there's no /direct/ dependency on `text`. So I can't wrap my head around how this works.

Comment: Well I got this issue and fixed in the same way, for some reason it doesnt see the updated value, tbh I dont know the actual reason :(

Comment: Ok, no worries, maybe someone else can jump in here. I've marked this as the correct answer anyway as it solved the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: The reason you need to pass text as a dependency is because `useLayoutEffect` won't run unless one of its dependencies changes and the navigation object doesn't change ever. When you added `text` as a dependency, it ensures that your `useLayoutEffect` function will run evreytime text changes. Which is what you want